# How are the inhabitants of Earth supposed to be transferred to Pandora?

Tags: spaceship, avatar, avatar-the-way-of-water

In my question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270528/67168), I asked about the political system on Earth during the time of the Avatar movie.

A comment by Klaus states

> In The Way of Water, it is briefly mentioned that the Earth is
> becoming unlivable, and Pandora is being prepared to be the new home
> of mankind.

Given the size of the interstellar ships used in the movies, how is it even remotely feasible to transport Earth's population to Pandora?  Or is the plan simply to abandon 99% of humans in the process?

In [How was the base on Pandora built in Avatar?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/229226/67168), it states that there are maybe 10 or 12 ships that take about 10 years to complete the journey (so double that for a return trip), and that while we see ships with a 350 ton payload, there may be ships with a 1000 ton payload.  None of this bodes well even for our current 7.8 billion population.

Comment: Build more ships

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, let's just knock out 10,000+ ships on a planet that is dying.

Comment: I have yet to come across a work with anything like a realistic setting that describes a way to migrate a major fraction of Earth's population off Earth.  Orbital energy just for LEO is about 9kWh/kg, so assuming around 200kg per person (including a few kg of personal effects and 100kg of oxygen, water and food, counting on external recycling and assuming their accommodation is constructed in space), just the energy cost of moving half Earth's population to orbit would be OOM 10 petaWatt hours, or about 50 years of the world's total energy production as of 2022.

Comment: @PeterM - If the environment was less of a concern, then building spaceships would be easier, not harder

Comment: @DavidW if we imagine a society that has self-replicating mining and manufacturing machines, in principle you could set one loose in say the asteroid belt and thanks to exponential growth soon convert the vast majority of matter in the belt to starships or whatever else you want. But authors who think through the social implications of self-replicating manufacturing machines tend to conclude it would lead to the end of capitalism as we know it (some kind of alternative 'post-scarcity economy' a la Star Trek or The Culture), which wouldn't fit with human civilization in Avatar universe.

Comment: @Valorum Getting OT, but if 7+ billion people trashed the Earth to the point it was non-viable, what are 7+ billion people going to do on Pandora?

Comment: @PeterM - I'm guessing all the poor people people will be staying behind

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'm not talking about that.  I'm talking about the plain energy cost of lifting billions of people off the surface of Earth.  (Which would actually be at least an order of magnitude higher, considering most people won't survive infinite acceleration, and limiting acceleration to 3g or so multiplies gravity losses by a factor of around 9, plus most people would want to be in some kind of hard enclosure to maintain a livable environment, limit radiation etc.)  You start running into thermodynamic issues cooling Earth to livable temperatures, assuming the energy is available.

Comment: @DavidW You just create an Earth shattering kaboom, *et voila*, no need to lift all those people into space!

Comment: @DavidW Good point about energy (as opposed to economic) cost of lifting all those humans off Earth and consequent waste heat issues, but space elevators might be possible in Avatar universe, and lifting a person slowly into space that way might not generate much more waste heat that moving them along a horizontal monorail of same length. But without something like self-replicating machines that can convert vast amount of raw material into space elevators, the rate people could leave Earth that way presumably wouldn't be enough for substantial fraction of population to leave in say 100 yrs.

Comment: And that energy is peanuts compared to what's needed to push all those people, along with 1000+ metric tons of spacecraft, up to 25% lightspeed and down again.

Comment: @BMF - See the last sentence of DavidW's most recent comment, I think he was making the point that even if we assume for the sake of argument that vast amounts of energy were available (say, by using self-replicating machines to turn some large fraction of the matter in the asteroid belt into solar collectors and another large fraction into antimatter manufacturing facilities to fuel starships), using that energy to move the population off earth w/ rockets would generate so much waste heat that you'd only be able to transport a small % away before it'd get too hot for the rest to survive.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Space elevators are a bit more efficient.

Comment: @DavidW There's the solution they use in Xenoblade Chronicles X - rather than actually transport the population, they scan their minds into a computer, and then the ships just contain the scanned data plus a replicator that can reproduce the human bodies if matter is fed into it, and download the scanned minds back into the replicated bodies.

Comment: @Showsni thats what I was just about to comment - they already demonstrate this capability in the first 10 minutes of the movie, so its plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thier consciousness will be transferred but not the bodies. Maybe put in Navi bodies too so they don't have to terraform

Comment: Might be worth adding that we know humans have the tech to do this since in *Way of Water* we saw that Quaritch's brain state had been saved before the death of his human body, and they were able to transfer it to an avatar body.